# Batch file exception on purpose

Tags: batch-file

I want to build a "faulty" batch file on purpose, that throws an exception to test my programm for exception handling. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a line `exit 1` (or another integer). You can also print an error to the error stream (before the exit command) with `echo fatal error >&2` , but the exit code is the way to indicate something wrong with your script `0` is for successful execution and everything else is considered as error.

More about the command -> https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html  , https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html